# SVN branching subdirectory of trunk

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When I create a branch of subfolder in SVN and then try to merge trunk changes to this branch SVN tries to merge revisions from 1 to HEAD and this results in huge list of tree conflicts.

I'm using TortoiseSVN and we have a SVN repository with a structure like this:

```
 -> root
    ->Docs
    ->Code
       ->trunk
           ->project
              ->module1
              ->module2
       ->branches
          ->v1
          ->v2
```

What I want is just create a branch of module1 in branches\module1_test and from time to time merge changes from trunk\project\module1 to bracnhes\module1_test and then reintegrate test branch in trunk.

But for some reason when I do Merge->Merge a range of revisions in turtoiseSVN it tries to merge 1-HEAD from trunk and it produces lots of tree conficts, why it's not using the revision of when the branch was made.

Comment: I have just found an article where it is said that if you want to branch subdirectory it's better to branch everything and checkout only directory you want to work with. http://www.tranquillo.net/2010/03/04/better-branching-in-subversion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are merging module1 to module1_test, not not specifying any rev it will take all module1 revisions i.e., 1-head

So, you need to specify the revision which would be the rev (when the branch was created) to head.

Comment: Why it can't do it automaticaly? What about situation when I have synced with trunk and comited this to branch, what version should I use next time I merge changes from trunk? when the branch was created or when I did last sync?

Comment: You have to do it from the last revision synced.  Also, since a long time svn has started keeping merge info in the revisions, which means when you merge module1 to module_test, module_test will have this info that you merged xyz rev of module1. I don't know if this feature can more intelligently be used.